# Check Whether the OS Type of the Remote Machine is 2008 R2 by Powershell Command

Tags: c++, windows, operating-system, remote-server

I used the below command in my c++ code to get the system information of a remote machine

```
systeminfo /s 192.168.102.34 /u Administrator
```

But I need to check whether the OS Type of the remote machine is 2008 R2 using a c++ code. So i want to take the OS type alone. How do i compare it with the os type alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
wmic /Node:hostname os get Name
```